# Remove items from NEI

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I use 1.7.10 Minecraft. I have many pages with Forge Microblocks in Not Enough Items and no one uses them. How can I remove items from Not Enough Items?

Comment: In AgrarianSkies, there's a mod called gtfoMicroblocks. Maybe a quick google search will enlighten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AgrarianSkies, a commonly used modpack, employs a mod called gtfoMicroblocks. What it does is simply what you said, removed all microblock items from NEI. It does not affect any other part of the game.

gtfoMicroblocks link: http://openeye.openmods.info/mod/gtfomicroblocks

Comment: Hey, but gtfoMicroblocks is for 1.6.4, but I said I use 1.7.10!

Comment: Poke the mod author, not much I can do about that.